# In RAILS3 - When Creating a Record with 3 columns - how to only accept if all 3 are populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model in Rails 3. When creating the record, there are a total of 3 columns for the model.

Right now, Rails allows for creating a record if only 2 of the 3 records are populated?

In rails, how do you tell Rails only create a record if 3 values for each column exist when creating?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :login, :email
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_presence_of

Comment: Interesting. So that worked from preventing the record from being created. BUT it isn't triggering an error. "    respond_to do |format|
      if @mymodel.save
" stillgoes through?

Comment: I think Rails 3 is like Rails 2, when it doesn't validate, it will go back to the form stating the error, and can even have the invalid field highlighted.